# Hello I keep getting the error "return type must be 'void' to match overridden member" and I can't seem to fix it

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

Here is my code. I keep getting the same `error` and I can't seem to resolve it.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
namespace CreatingCharacters.Abilities
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMovementController))]
    public class genjidash : Ability
    {
        [SerializeField] private float dashForce;
        [SerializeField] private float dashDuration;
        private PlayerMovementController playerMovementController;
        private void Awake()
        {
            playerMovementController = GetComponent<PlayerMovementController>();
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                StartCoroutine(Cast());
            }
        }
        public override IEnumerator Cast()
        {
            playerMovementController.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward, dashForce);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashDuration);
            playerMovementController.ResetImpact()
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code that it is parented to:

```
using UnityEngine;
namespace CreatingCharacters.Abilities
{   
    public abstract class Ability : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public abstract void Cast();
    }
}
```

Any advise would be great and thank you in advance.

Comment: `public abstract void Cast();` this is "void" return . you need fix it to `public abstract IEnumerator Cast()`

Comment: The error really couldn't be clearer. You've changed the type of a method that you `override`. That's not valid

Comment: Well, you are trying to override a `void` function with one that returns an `IEnumerator`. As the message points out, you can't do that. If you think about it. It makes no sense. The fact that `Cast` is abstract means you must implement an override. But your callers will be calling a method that is declared to return nothing. You're going to surprise them and return something.

Answer (score 3):

class `genjidash` is derived from `Ability`, the return of `Cast()` in `Ability` is void, but in `genjidash` it's IEnumerator, so maybe you should change your base `Cast()` to

```
public abstract class Ability : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract IEnumerator Cast();
}
```

If you can't change Ability's Cast(), you need

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        StartCoroutine(CastAndReset());
    }
}
private IEnumrator CastAndReset()
{
    Cast();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashDuration);
    playerMovementController.ResetImpact()
}
public override void Cast()
{
    playerMovementController.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward, dashForce);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. I am still learning the basics. Thank you again.